# AWS DynamoDB Insert Multiple Attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to insert multiple values for one primary key on DynamoDB AWS.

For example:

Primarykey: 1  Customer: "a","b"

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably customer is neither the partition nor the sort key, but is a simple attribute that needs to have multiple values.

Yes, DynamoDB attributes can be multi-valued. You would use the `SS` data type, which is a string set.